# Typeahead in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

I am new to angular js. I am trying to implement typeahead for the json data I get:
format of json data is like:

```
$scope.utilstates = [
    { "State": "Florida", "Key": "FL", "Utility": [ "Bartow (City of) Electric", "Clay Electric Co-Op", "Florida Power & Light", "FMG", "Gainesville Regional Utilities", "Gulf Power Company" ] },
    { "State": "Texas", "Key": "TX", "Utility": [ "AEP-Texas (SWEPCO)", "Austin Energy", "Brownsville Public Utilities Board (TX)", "CenterPoint Energy (Reliant - HL&P)"] },
    { "State": "Virginia", "Key": "VA", "Utility": [ "DVP", "NOVEC"] }
];
```

In the html, I want the user to enter the utility company irrespective of state and should show the matching utility company.

in  html, I have this code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query.utility" typeahead="st as st.Utility for st in utilstates | filter:({Utility:$viewValue}) | limitTo:8" class="form-control" placeholder="Utilities">
```

But I get complete array of values, instead of selected value from the matched array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/no0hATW5mHiIbuON6B9E?p=preview

Comment: You are using very old version of Angular and AngularUI. Pretty sure this is the problem.

Comment: I changed to new version. Still I am getting array of values and not the specific value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. The reason why you got array of objects after selecting is that `as st.Utility` after **as** keyword you have to provide the expression that will be visible in typeahead prompt and after selecting in text input.

First expression just after **for** (in your case `st`) will lead to receive whole object from `utilstates` instead of desired `Utility`.

Secondly. You cannot point particular item from nested array in object that is the element of typeahead selection without helper methods and much complicating your code.

My advise is to reconsider the data structure of those Utilities. Maybe instead of array of whole states, make an array of single utilities. For example:

```
var utilities = [{
    State: "Virginia",
    Key: "VA",
    Name: "AEP-Texas (SWEPCO)"
}//And so on...]
```

then you can easly go with:

`utility as utility.Name for utility in utilities`

Comment: ok. I changed the format of the data structure and I am able to address the problem. But for the state field, I am seeing duplicate values. I tried use 'unique' but it is not working.. Any help?

Comment: If you have duplicated records across different (for example) states you can create your own promtp template. And display `AEP-Texas (SWEPCO) - Virginia` and `AEP-Texas (SWEPCO) - Texas` etc.

Comment: You used unique filter like this ? `| unique:'state'`

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a helper function that concatenates all the arrays together in a new $scope array and use:

`<input type="text" ng-model="query.utility" typeahead="util for util in Utilities | limitTo:8" class="form-control" placeholder="Utilities">`.

The problem is that you need to iterate over the array to get the values instead of the array. For example:

`typeahead="st as st.Utility[1] for st in utilstates"`

will return the second value in each array. Perhaps there is a better way to do this in the `typeahead` than the above code, but the above works.

Comment: moving all utils to a $scope variable was my last option. I was told that, later stage, I need to sort the utils based on State. So the first filter would be state and then use the array of the selected state utilities.